# Внутренний анонимный класс

Tags: java, наследование

Не могу понять почему при использовании super.getName() я получаю вывод "sout".Да метод объявлен как приватный,но через конструктор наследника*** все равно name присваивается "sout".

```
public class Solution {
    private String name;

    Solution(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private void sout() {
        new Solution("sout") {
            void printName() {
                System.out.println(super.getName());
            }
        }.printName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Solution("main").sout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну так вы и не запрашиваете имя основного класса `getName()`, а метод который создает **НОВЫЙ** объект внутри того что создан в `main` с именем "sout".

Суперкласс к которому вы обращаетесь с помощью `super.` в анонимном классе, это не объект класса в котором он размещается, а все тот же внутренний объект, но с изначальными методами.

Этот оборот нужен в том случае, если вы переопределили какой-то метод в подклассе и хотите вызвать его изначальную версию. Если он не был переопределен, то даже super ставить не надо.