# Анонимные классы в Java

Tags: java

Друзья, помогите прояснить один момент..
Правильно ли я понимаю, что создавая анонимный класс на основе другого класса (не важно - абстрактный или нет), анонимный класс будет являться дочерним по отношению к тому от которого его создали?

Например:

```
new A(){
    // переопределяем какой-нибудь метод
};
```

т.е. А - супер класс, а анонимный - его потомок.

Заранее спасибо.

upd

```
System.out.println(getClass().getName());
System.out.println(super.getClass().getName());
```

Оба раза выводится одно и то же имя анонимного класса (с единицей). выходит у анонимного класса нет родителя.

Comment: да, должен им быть.

Comment: Может быть я ошибаюсь, но мне кажется, что это не так, т.к. это идентично объявлению подкласса внутри класса (т.е. вы же не наследуетесь от класса, в котором создаете подкласс, а лишь создаете в его пространстве имен, если это можно так назвать), аналогично вопросу [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504131/%D0%92%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81).

Comment: можно проверить с помощью instanceof

Comment: Из документации: "The anonymous class expression consists of the following: ... The name of an interface to implement or a class to extend". Ну и как бы аннотации `@Override` также это подтверждают.

Comment: Такс, извиняюсь, прочитал документацию, свой косяк понял :)

Comment: `object.getClass()` возвращает объект `Class` для настоящего класса (времени выполнения/runtime) объекта, плюс он объявлен, как `final`, поэтому его нет смысла вызывать через `super`. Если нужно получить родительский класс, то вызовите `getClass().getSuperclass()`.

Comment: zRrr, спасибо за очень полезный комментарий.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вопрос по абстрактным классам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610430/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc)