# Вопрос по абстрактным классам

Tags: java, классы

Существует абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class Drink
{
    public void taste(){
        System.out.println("Вкусно");
    }
}
```

По идее создавать его экземпляры запрещено, но IDE помог обойти этот запрет следующим способом:

```
public static Drink getDeliciousDrink() {
        return new Drink()
        {
            @Override
            public void taste()
            {
                super.taste();
            }
        };
    }
```

Что происходит при переопределении функции taste и почему я могу создать экземпляр этого класса?

Comment: Вы правильно понимаете, это будет экземпляр _другого_ класса (анонимного).

Comment: Смотрим доку [Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

Comment: я новичок совсем, но помню что во всех книжках написано, что нельзя создать объект абстрактного класса

Comment: Хорошо, что не пошли туда работать.

Comment: @Vadik ей пока неизвестен результат собеседования, но мы вместе пришли к выводу, что с таким руководителем могут возникнуть проблемы и от трудоустройства лучше воздержаться, тем более, что это было не единственное заблуждение интервьюера

Comment: Конечно нельзя создать экземпляр абстрактного класса, это уже будет анонимный класс, который скомпилируется во внутренний. А вообще пригласите этого интервьюера сюда на стековерфлоу, послушаем его версию и аргументы с ссылками на документацию)) может он нам даже ответ напишет))

Comment: Читай [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/837449/204920).

Comment: @Sergey Zh. было бы крайне интересно увидеть здесь его доводы, но я его контактов не имею. Если получится - приглашу :)

Comment: Здесь ac - это экземляр реализации абстракного класса, а не самого класса. С таким же успехом можно говорить, что мы можем создать экземпляр интерфейса

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы не создаете экземпляр класса `Drink`. Конструкция

```
new Drink()
{
    @Override
    public void taste()
    {
        super.taste();
    }
}
```

Определяет анонимный **подкласс** класса `Drink` с переопределенным методом `taste`и создает экземпляр этого подкласса. Т.к. базовый класс только объявлен абстрактным, но не содержит абстрактных методов, то его наследников вполне можно создавать. Более того, т.к. в этом подклассе переопределяется только один метод, который, по сути, просто вызывает метод родителя, то можно написать и так

```
public static Drink getDeliciousDrink() {
    return new Drink(){};
}
```

Comment: Понятно, я как-то не дошел еще до изучения анонимных классов.) Есть же еще конструкция когда создается объект интерфейс-класса, но получает ссылку реального объекта List<> a = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 7):

#### Можно ли создать экземпляр абстрактного класса?

Чистый экземпляр абстрактного класса создать **нельзя**. Что же происходит в вашем случае? Вы создаёте *анонимный класс*. Но это утверждение **неверно**:

> с помощью анонимного класса будет получен экземпляр абстрактного класса.

Чтобы понять, почему я объясню, как это работает "под капотом".

#### А что тогда на самом деле происходит?

Когда вы создаёте анонимный класс таким образом:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AbstractClass ac = new AbstractClass() {
        @Override
        void doSomething() {
             //Реализация
        }
    };
}
```

Происходит вот что:

1. Создаётся *локальный* класс (то есть класс внутри метода, подробнее о локальных классах например [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/440068/)). Но этот локальный класс наследуется от вашего абстрактного класса. Выглядит это как-то так:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class NameOfOuterClass$1 extends AbstractClass {
        @Override
        void doSomething() {
             //Реализация
        }
    }
}
```

Кстати, при компиляции анонимные классы превращаются в файлы `.class` с именами что-то вроде `Имя_внешнего_класса$1`.

2. А `ac` - не экземпляр абстрактного класса, а экземпляр того самого локального класса, то есть был создан `jvm` как-то так:

```
NameOfOuterClass$1 ac = new NameOfOuterClass$1();
```

А Интервьюер хотел просто запутать вашу коллегу, чтобы проверить, знает ли он(а), что на самом деле происходит.

#### Как всё-таки *доказать*, что это экземпляр не абстрактного класса, а анонимного?

Спасибо `@Nofate` за идею. Действительно, есть способ, как ***доказать***, что это экземпляр анонимного класса, а не абстрактного. Вот собственно способ:

```java
public static void main(String [] args){ 
     AbstractClass ac = new AbstractClass() {
        @Override
        void doSomething() {
             //Реализация
        }
     };

     //Проверяем, является ли ac объектом абстрактного класса
     System.out.println(ac.getClass().equals(AbstractClass.class));
  }
```

Мы просто проверяем с помощью метода `equals()` , вернёт метод `getClass()` (вызванный на объекте `ac`)  объект, который является объектом абстрактного класса.

Comment: Мой ответ неверен?

Comment: Да не то чтобы неверен (минус не мой), я просто предлагаю перед ответом на старый вопрос проверить,  нет ли у него дубликата с принятым ответом.

Comment: можно еще добавить, что самый простой способ в этом убедиться: `(new AbstractClass() {}).getClass().equals(AbstractClass.class)`

Comment: @Nofate большое вам спасибо за идею! Завтра допишу про это. Возможно, это поможет мне решить проблему, о которой я писал на мете.

Comment: Если минусы связаны с подозрением в дубликате, то я описал ситуацию [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12476/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%88%d1%91%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: Товарищи минусаторы - высказывайтесь по существу, чем ответ неправилен, как его улучшить? Раз уж тут вас такой наплыв, то пока от вас нету комментариев - придется поставить компенсационный плюс )