# Может ли абстрактный метод находиться в неабстрактном классе?

Tags: java, классы, методы, uml, диаграммы

Поясните пожалуйста момент с UML диаграммы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понял, что абстрактные методы и классы пишутся в диаграмме курсивом. Как тогда абстрактный метод может находиться не в абстрактном классе?

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Абстрактный метод *не может* находиться не в абстрактном классе.

Это же самое описано и в [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html):

> Абстрактный класс - это класс, объявленный `abstract` - он может
>   включать или не включать абстрактные методы. Объекты не
>   могут быть созданы из абстрактных классов, но они могут быть объектами, созданными из подклассов.
>
> Абстрактный метод - это метод, объявленный без реализации (без
>   фигурных скобок и с запятой), например:
>
> ```
> abstract void moveTo(double deltaX, double deltaY);
> ```
>
> Если класс включает абстрактные методы, то сам класс *должен* быть
>   объявлен `abstract`, как в:
>
> ```
> public abstract class GraphicObject {
>     // объявлять поля
>     // объявлять неабстрактные методы
>     abstract void draw ();
> }
> ```
>
> Когда абстрактный класс является подклассом, подкласс обычно
>   предоставляет реализации для всех абстрактных методов в его
>   родительском классе. Однако, если это не так, то подкласс также
>   *должен* быть объявлен `abstract`.

Comment: Так я понимаю, да и компилятор подсвечивает. Однако сопровождающая диаграмму литература говорит:"Мы можем сделать метод получения сотрудников в базовом классе компании абстрактным.". Сам же класс не абстрактен. Как так?

Comment: базовый класс будет абстрактным, а подкласс не абстрактен

Comment: Я понимаю, но вопрос то конкретно по этой диаграмме.

Что в данном случае базовый класс? Company? Абстрактным он быть не может. И от абстрактного класса он не наследуется, а даже если бы и наследовался то ему всё - равно пришлось бы стать абстрактным чтобы быть способным содержать getEmployees();

Comment: Базовый класс `Company`, так как от него наследуются другие классы, которых не видно на вашей диаграмме. Стрелочка с треугольником показывают это графически.  `getEmployees()` является абстрактным методом, потому что  изображен италикой. Следовательно `Company` является абстрактным и должен быть изображен италикой, по крайней мере в Java так. Может быть вы ввели меня в заблуждение поставив неверный тэг и тогда мой ответ будет специфичным. [Голубь](https://holub.com/uml/) на своих диаграммах не рисует италику, хотя пишет что абстрактные классы и интерфейсы надо изображать италикой.