# Как выполнить метод дочернего класса из родительского

Tags: java, ооп

Есть родительский класс, который является абстракцией при создании экземпляров дочерних классов.

Как можно с инстанса родителя, получить доступ к методам дочернего класса?

```
class A {
 //some code
}

class B extends A {
 private int i = 10;
 public void go() {
  //some code
 }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
A a = new B();
a.go();//error
```

Comment: думаю никак, хотя я тоже только обучаюсь

Comment: ( (B) a ).go();

Comment: Всем спасибо! Думал есть иной способ, которого я не знаю, но видать нету. В ответах ничего нового для себя не узнал, но все-таки отмечу один как правильный.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Привести тип переменной к дочернему классу:

```
A a = new B();
((B) a).go();
```

Проблема в том, что переменная может хранить объект класса `A` и других его наследников, у которых метода `go` не будет. Поэтому может потребоваться сначала проверить содержит ли переменная объект нужного класса:

```
if(a instanceof B) {
    B b = (B) a;
    b.go();
}
```

А вообще сам факт того что Вам понадобилось приведение типов это повод задуматься и поработать над логикой кода. Почему переменная объявлена с типом `A`? Всегда ли там будет объект класса `B`? Не нужно ли перенести метод в родительский класс? Не лучше ли создать метод в `A` и переопределить его поведение в `B`?

Answer (score 1):

Если все дочерние классы имеют такой метод то можно задекларировать его в базовом классе.

```
abstract class A {
    public abstract void go();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в  классе `A` нет метода, то вызвать из него метод другого класса нельзя. Но если добавить метод с такой же сигнатурой и возвращаемым значением в класс `A`, то в `B` этот метод будет перекрыт, и следовательно вызываться благодаря полиморфизму.

Метод и класс `A` можно сделать абстрактным, если нет общей имплементации по умолчанию для подклассов, и следовательно подклассам придётся писать свою имплеметацию.

Если класс `А` не абстрактный, но содержит метод, который перекрыт в подклассе, то вызов метода будет происходить из подкласса, благодаря тому же полиморфизму, но подклассы в этом случае не обязаны имплементировать или перекрывать общий метод, который будет иметь имплементацию по умолчанию.

Для более лучшего понимания абстрактных классов можно почитать [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/837449/204920) ответ.