# Зачем ставить спецификацию abstract перед классом в Java?

Tags: java

По определению: Абстрактный класс - это класс имеющий хотя бы один абстрактный метод.
Абстрактный класс без абстрактного метода по определению не является абстрактным. Тогда для какой цели мы используем спецификацию abstract перед классом. Если мы делаем абстрактный метод в классе, то почему класс автоматически не становится абстрактным?

Один из источников информации: Научно-популярное издание
Герберт Шилдт
Java: руководство для начинающих, 7-е издание
Стр. 715

Comment: Наверное чтобы явно зрительно дать понять разработчикам, что он таковым является))) Особенно, если абстрактный метод может быть где-то далеко внизу)) ............. ну и.......абстрактный класс может не содержать абстрактных методов вовсе.... тогда нужно в любом случае писать это слово.......так что, считайте, что ещё и для стандартизации и **консистентности**

Comment: Если абстрактный класс может существовать без абстрактного метода, то тогда это не сходится с определение абстрактного класса, что не допустимо. Для зрительного восприятия это единственный логичный ответ, что приходит на ум. Спасибо!

Comment: А где вы достали такое определение, что "Абстрактный класс - это класс имеющий хотя бы один абстрактный метод" ?

Comment: Таки да - только что проверил - прекрасно создаётся абстрактный класс без методов.

Comment: https://ideone.com/COTHqZ  ............ причём `new Test()` вызовет `Test is abstract; cannot be instantiated
  new Test();`

Comment: Я читал информацию в интернете. Вот парень ниже пишет: Абстрактный класс – это класс, содержащий методы, которые не имеют реализации - значит это абстрактные методы. Если определение неверно, то тогда вопрос будет снят. Я пытаюсь найти истину. Спасибо что помогаете.

Comment: Скажем так, в JDK 1  действительно абстрактный класс должен был иметь хотя бы один абстрактный метод.... Сейчас в Java это не так. Сейчас даже интерфейс может содержать дефолтные методы (о ужас, да?))). Я бы сказал так, что абстрактный класс - это класс, который **может** содержать абстрактные свойства и методы.

Comment: Хотя вот в каких-либо других языках возможно и есть ограничение на то, что должен быть хотя бы один абстрактный метод. Здесь не берусь сказать. Всех их (тысячу) не знаю

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо большое за ответы. Приму на веру. Хотя мне пока не понятна целесообразность абстрактных классов без абстрактных методов. Надеюсь когда-нибудь я разберусь. Спасибо.

Comment: [https://overcoder.net/q/214667/зачем-использовать-абстрактный-класс-без-абстрактных-методов](https://overcoder.net/q/214667/зачем-использовать-абстрактный-класс-без-абстрактных-методов)   +  https://stackoverflow.com/q/4811678/6104996

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Видимо ошибка в книге, которую я читаю, она ввела меня в заблуждение. Еще раз благодарю Вас.

Comment: "Абстрактный класс - это класс имеющий хотя бы один абстрактный метод" -- нет такого определения. "Я читал информацию в интернете"  -- не всему написанному в интернете можно верить. Читайте авторитетные источники. Самый авторитетный -- это спецификация языка. Книжки типа Шилдта тоже можно читать, но всегда надо проверять, про какую версию языка в книжке идет речь. Ну и в книжках не все нюансы описаны, все просто в книжку не поместятся.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Может ли абстрактный метод находиться в неабстрактном классе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837442/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2):

Абстрактный класс -- это такой класс, экземпляры которого нельзя создавать. Он может иметь абстрактные методы, может не иметь абстрактных методов, и может не иметь вообще никаких методов, это никак не регламентируется. Класс помечается как абстрактный тогда, когда он предназначен **исключительно** для того, чтобы наследовать от него другие классы, которые могут быть как абстрактными, так и нет. Не может быть, например, экземпляра `животного`. Может быть экземпляр `кошки`, которая является частным случаем (потомком) `животного`, может быть экземпляр `собаки`, экземпляр `коровы`, но не экземпляр *абстрактного* `животного`.

Смысл в этом вот какой. Если вы используете классы из библиотеки, разработанной кем-то другим (а это обычная ситуация), то не разобравшись, вы можете попытаться создавать и использовать объекты классов, которые для этого не предназначены. В этом случае вы получите странное поведение программы, которое не было предусмотрено ни вами, ни разработчиком библиотеки. Именно для защиты от такого рода ошибок в языке и предусмотрена возможность помечать классы, как *абстрактные*. При попытке создать экземпляр абстрактного класса компилятор выдаст ошибку и не позволит вам это сделать.

Примерами абстрактных классов в стандартной библиотеке являются `InputStream` и `Number`. Вы можете создавать `BufferedInputStream`, `DataInputStream` и экземпляры прочих специализированных потоков ввода, но не абстрактный `InputStream`. Вы можете создавать `Double`, `Long`, `BogDecimal` и экземпляры прочих числовых типов, но не абстрактный `Number`.

Примерами

Answer (score 0):

Абстрактный класс - это тот класс, который не может иметь собственных экземпляров (объектов). Если брать более точное определение: Абстрактный класс – это класс, содержащий методы, которые не имеют реализации. Абстрактный класс создается с целью создания общего интерфейса между разными реализациями классов, которые будут производными от абстрактного класса. Абстрактный класс создается для определения некоторых общих черт производных от него классов, которые определяют конкретную его реализацию.

Ваше определение в корне неверно. Не понимаю смысла Вашего вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это понятно. Вопрос немного в другом.

Comment: Вы пишите: Абстрактный класс – это класс, содержащий методы, которые не имеют реализации. Так? А теперь проверяйте что будет если сделать так:

public abstract class TwoDShape {
    //abstract public double area();
}

Comment: @Антон тогда ты получишь интерфейс, который тебе придётся реализовать (шутка).

Comment: к сожалению я шутку не понял, так как пока не дошел еще. Но как дойду прочту комментарий еще раз))))

Comment: @Антон как скажешь.

Comment: Я на полном серьёзе. Без обид. Пока только разбираюсь со всем этим.

Comment: @Антон посмотри, что такое интерфейс, и тогда поймешь.

Answer (score 0):

Считаю что в книге допущена ошибка, определение абстрактного класса дано не верно. Абстрактный класс не обязан иметь абстрактный метод, чтобы считаться абстрактным. Поэтому обоснованные вопросы теряют смысл.